# XeTeX vs LuaTeX operator limits

Tags: xetex, luatex, scripts

To compare the `\nolimits` algorithms for operators for XeTeX and LuaTeX, I tested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
   \[ \int_0^\infty \]
\end{document}'
```

I got the following results for XeTeX (0.99996) and LuaTeX (0.95), respectively.

[image: XeTeX] [image: LuaTeX]

I understand the algorithm that LuaTeX used to obtain the results shown: after determining the heights of the superscript and subscript, the horizontal kerning is taken to be `ic/2` for the superscript and `-ic/2` for the subscript, where `ic` is the italics correction for the integral operator.  What I don't understand is what XeTeX used.

What algorithm is XeTeX using?  As far as I know the only font parameters provided to XeTeX from XITS is the italics correction information for the integral sign.

**Edit:** As of LuaTeX 0.99, no longer is the superscript kerned right by `ic/2` and the subscript kerned left by `ic/2` by default.  Now the default is to not kern the superscript, and to kern the subscript left by `3/4 ic`.  This parameter can be modified by `\mathnolimitsmode`.  See the section *Nolimit correction* in the LuaTeX reference for more information.

Comment: FWIW, placement of integral bounds in LuaTeX seems still broken.

Comment: @egreg in miktex (with luatex 1.0 and the prerelease luaotfload) it looks ok.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Happy to know!!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks.  It appears that LuaTeX changed their default configuration and introduce a new nolimits mode.  To quote LuaTeX's source: `int mode = nolimits_mode_par; /* wins */`.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

With STIX Math Two instead of XITS Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
   \[ \int_0^\infty \]
\end{document}
```

I get the following outputs.

### XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)

[image]

### LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)

[image]

### XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)

[image]

### LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)

[image]

### Summary

It seems that LuaTeX 1.0.4 has fixed the bug with integrals. And STIX Two Math fixes other aspects of XITS Math.

Note: TeX Live 2017 is due tomorrow (2017-06-04) at time of writing this answer.